# Auto forward non alias emails to our G Suite domain

Tags: gmail, email, google-workspace-for-business

To group emails from projects we send them to a project mail address (for example all mails of project "Vanardenne" are sent to "Vanardenne@reekmansverandabouw.be". To achieve this we make an extra alias. Is there a way to automatically forward these emails without having to make the alias?

Comment: This works perfect!
Is there a way to rearange it so we can use autocomplete (if i can put Vanardenne it is the only mail i receive)

If this is not possible i will add the i@reekmansverandabouw.be as alias :)

Comment: added as an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a plus sign and any word before the **`@`** sign (e.g. **`emma.grey+project.1@gmail.com`**) and messages will still reach you. This way you can create an unlimited amount of new/unique email addresses for each occasion you need like: **`your.regular.email+Vanardenne@reekmansverandabouw.be`**